# Joining PySpark dataframes with conditional result column

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have these tables:

```
df1                  df2
+---+------------+   +---+---------+
| id|   many_cols|   | id|criterion|
+---+------------+   +---+---------+
|  1|lots_of_data|   |  1|    false|
|  2|lots_of_data|   |  1|     true|
|  3|lots_of_data|   |  1|     true|
+---+------------+   |  3|    false|
                     +---+---------+
```

I intend to create additional column in `df1`:

```
+---+------------+------+
| id|   many_cols|result|
+---+------------+------+
|  1|lots_of_data|     1|
|  2|lots_of_data|  null|
|  3|lots_of_data|     0|
+---+------------+------+
```

`result` should be `1` if there is a corresponding `true` in `df2`
`result` should be `0` if there's no corresponding `true` in `df2`
`result` should be `null` if there is no corresponding `id` in `df2`

I cannot think of an efficient way to do it. I am stuck with only the 3rd condition working after a join:

```py
df = df1.join(df2, 'id', 'full')
df.show()

#  +---+------------+---------+
#  | id|   many_cols|criterion|
#  +---+------------+---------+
#  |  1|lots_of_data|    false|
#  |  1|lots_of_data|     true|
#  |  1|lots_of_data|     true|
#  |  3|lots_of_data|    false|
#  |  2|lots_of_data|     null|
#  +---+------------+---------+
```

PySpark dataframes are created like this:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

df1cols = ['id', 'many_cols']
df1data = [(1, 'lots_of_data'),
           (2, 'lots_of_data'),
           (3, 'lots_of_data')]
df2cols = ['id', 'criterion']
df2data = [(1, False),
           (1, True),
           (1, True),
           (3, None)]
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(df1data, df1cols)
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(df2data, df2cols)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to merge the ideas of proposed answers to get the solution which suited me most.

```
# The `cond` variable is very useful, here it represents several complex conditions
cond = F.col('criterion') == True
df2_grp = df2.select(
    'id',
    F.when(cond, 1).otherwise(0).alias('c')
).groupBy('id').agg(F.max(F.col('c')).alias('result'))
df = df1.join(df2_grp, 'id', 'left')

df.show()
#+---+------------+------+
#| id|   many_cols|result|
#+---+------------+------+
#|  1|lots_of_data|     1|
#|  3|lots_of_data|     0|
#|  2|lots_of_data|  null|
#+---+------------+------+
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple way would be to groupby `df2` to get the max `criterion` by `id` the join with `df1`, this way you reduce the number of lines to join. The max of a boolean column is true if there is at least one corresponding true value:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df2_group = df2.groupBy("id").agg(F.max("criterion").alias("criterion"))

result = df1.join(df2_group, ["id"], "left").withColumn(
    "result",
    F.col("criterion").cast("int")
).drop("criterion")

result.show()
#+---+------------+------+
#| id|   many_cols|result|
#+---+------------+------+
#|  1|lots_of_data|     1|
#|  3|lots_of_data|     0|
#|  2|lots_of_data|  null|
#+---+------------+------+
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try a correlated subquery to get the maximum Boolean from df2, and cast that to an integer.

```
df1.createOrReplaceTempView('df1') 
df2.createOrReplaceTempView('df2') 

df = spark.sql("""
    select
        df1.*,
        (select int(max(criterion)) from df2 where df1.id = df2.id) as result
    from df1
""")

df.show()
+---+------------+------+
| id|   many_cols|result|
+---+------------+------+
|  1|lots_of_data|     1|
|  3|lots_of_data|     0|
|  2|lots_of_data|  null|
+---+------------+------+
```

Answer (score 1):

check out this solution. After joining. you can use multiple condition checks based on your requirement and assign the value accordingly using when clause and then take the max value of result grouping by id and other columns. you can use window function as well to calculate the max of result if you are just using just id for the partition.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

df1cols = ['id', 'many_cols']
df1data = [(1, 'lots_of_data'),
           (2, 'lots_of_data'),
           (3, 'lots_of_data')]
df2cols = ['id', 'criterion']
df2data = [(1, False),
           (1, True),
           (1, True),
           (3, False)]
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(df1data, df1cols)
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(df2data, df2cols)

df2_mod =df2.withColumnRenamed("id", "id_2")

df3=df1.join(df2_mod, on=df1.id== df2_mod.id_2, how='left')

cond1 = (F.col("id")== F.col("id_2"))& (F.col("criterion")==1)
cond2 = (F.col("id")== F.col("id_2"))& (F.col("criterion")==0)
cond3 = (F.col("id_2").isNull())

df3.select("id", "many_cols", F.when(cond1, 1).when(cond2,0).when(cond3, F.lit(None)).alias("result"))\
    .groupBy("id", "many_cols").agg(F.max(F.col("result")).alias("result")).orderBy("id").show()

Result:
------

+---+------------+------+
| id|   many_cols|result|
+---+------------+------+
|  1|lots_of_data|     1|
|  2|lots_of_data|  null|
|  3|lots_of_data|     0|
+---+------------+------+
```

Using window function

```
w=Window().partitionBy("id")

df3.select("id", "many_cols", F.when(cond1, 1).when(cond2,0).when(cond3, F.lit(None)).alias("result"))\
    .select("id", "many_cols", F.max("result").over(w).alias("result")).drop_duplicates().show()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the brilliant idea to refactor conditions into separate variables. It was the key in my real use case. However, since the final version evolved into a quite different thing, I cannot accept this as an answer. I gave one upvote, but you deserve at least two :)